# PopupMenuButton - how to disable animation

Tags: flutter, animation, popupmenubutton

Is there a way to disable animation after item selected? I have route to next page with slide animation and this route starts immediately when menu item is tapped. So I have 2 parallel animations (hiding popup menu and animated route).

Comment: seems that you have to delay your animated route by [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/e10df3c1a6/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/popup_menu.dart#L31) amount of time

Comment: Of course I can delay route animation, but prefer to disable popup animation :) Is it possible ?